# Finding solutions in a distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

Find the solution of $(x^2-\alpha^2)T=1, \alpha \in \mathbb{R^*}$,where $T$ is a distribution.

**My approach**

Solving the homogenous part will be $T=C_1\delta(-\alpha)+C_2\delta(\alpha)$

I do not know whether this is right or not. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why square root of $\alpha$?

Comment: Also check the case $\alpha=0$.